# Error 486 on start-of-line for regex but end-of-line works?

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

Am currently struggling with something simple that Google doesn't have an answer for. 
I recently procured a mac, and am trying to use Vim on it. However, both the homebrew version and inbuilt Vim on the machine have an issue where I cannot use the substitute command on the regex start-of-line character 'ˆ'.

For example, starting up a new file and creating some empty lines,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJeNx.jpg

Error 486...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/msyxt.jpg

Trying it with a different regex character,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3czl.jpg

This works? I'm confused
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXcdW.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a little exploration and asking questions on the #vim channel on freenode solved this.

turns out the character i was using was the accent character ˆ and not the ASCII character ^ that was required.

For any mac users that end up stumbling on here, press space after entering ˆ once to get the full ASCII ^